# How to read Android resource file values in unit testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I have an array resource. I want to make test to read and parse the values from xml resource. Here is the codes.

```
<string-array name="names">
    <item>Name1[?]200</item>
    <item>Name2[?]125</item>
    <item>Name3[?]142</item>
</string-array>
```

I want to capture above string resource and parse like below test case. But I couldn't achive.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ReadAndParseNamesTest {

@Mock
private Context mockApplicationContext;
@Mock
private Resources mockContextResources;

@Test
public void readAndParseNamesTest() {
    
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    when(mockApplicationContext.getResources()).thenReturn(mockContextResources);

     String[] marray = {"mock main class"};
    when(mockContextResources.getStringArray(R.array.allah_names))
            .thenReturn(marray);
    for(int i = 0;i<marray.length;i++){
        String[] deger = marray[i].split("[?]");
        System.out.println("Deger "+i+": "+deger[0] + " "+ deger[1]);
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1` exception because i can't get actual values. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use a simple mock to retrieve resource values.

Think of the case where you have both English and French string resources- which value should it resolve? The English or the French? When running pure JUnit tests, the test runner has no knowledge of resources such as these or how to resolve them.

There are a few approaches you can consider.

**Option 1: Don't worry about the values**
The first question to ask is what exactly you are testing and why.

You probably don't need to test that the Android framework is loading the resource values correctly. The framework has its own suite of tests and resource loading is generally reliable.

If you can trust that your resource values are correct, you only need to verify that you are calling `getStringArray()` with the correct string ID (`R.string.allah_names`).

**Option 2: Run instrumented tests**
If you truly want to test that the correct value is loaded, then you need to run an instrumented test of some sort using the actual Android framework.

These tests run on a physical device or an emulator.

If you want to go that route, check out the [Build instrumented unit tests documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests).

**Option 3: Use Robolectric**
As a sort of middle ground between instrumented tests and pure Java tests, [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) provides a "fake" Android SDK that can resolve resources, create Activities, etc.